# Deploying Mobile and Wear at the same time

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Is there a way to compile and deploy both the mobile and wear app at the same time from Android Studio?

I find myself making changes to both parts and then I need to wait for one to finish before I can deploy the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the default configurations for project names on Android Studio. You should have "mobile" and "wear" options in the launch combo.

1. Click on the arrow, choose "Edit Configurations..."
2. Select the "wear" application on the left list
3. On the right side, scroll down to "Before Launch"
4. Click on the green plus sign
5. Choose "Run another configuration"
6. Pick "mobile"
7. Use the arrows to make "mobile" first
8. Be sure to rebuild you project (FUll clean and build)
9. When you have "wear" selected, click on the green arrow to launch and it should launch both application in sequence with just one click.

I think that's the best we can do for now.

Comment: This used to work for me prior to Android Studio 2.0.  Now it launches the mobile app fine, but then blocks and never launches the wear