# Add Android Wear Module To My App

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to make an Android Wear that will be installed when you install the Phone's app from the play store.

I looked around and found that the way to do this is to create new Android Wear Module and build it there.

But, I have a problem with that. Because the phone module minimum SDK is 13 and the Wear Minimum SDK must be 20 (4.4W), I can't install the app itself on my phone, Only on the watch.

How can I fix this to work?
Thanks (And sorry about my not-so-good english).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phone `minSdkVersion` should stay the same (as it was - 13 in your case). The Wearable "part" of app should have `minSdkVersion` set to 20, but this is not a problem - Wearable app won't be installed on your phone (only on watch).

Phone apk just holds the wearable apk inside, but wearable apk doesn't affect phone app in any way.
The only constraint that wearable app adds (to the existing phone app) is that phone app manifest should include all permissions declared in wearable app manifest. That is because user have to agree for using all permissions (by "both" apps) at once.

Comment: I know that. But when I'm running (For debugging), It allows me to run the app only on the watch and not on the phone. How can I make it (Android Studio) to run my app on my phone and then the phone will transfer it's apk to the watch? I just want that running the app from the IDE will update both phone and wear.

Comment: "It allows me to run the app only on the watch and not on the phone." Because you shouldn't try to launch your wearable app on phone. You need to launch your phone app (that contains wearable `.apk` file inside). To learn how to package wearable app inside phone app please take a look at official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Comment: I see this. I added the first dependencies but I still can't update phone and wear in a single "Run" (Which I'm using only for debugging and not building right now).

Comment: Phone app will NOT install wearable part on watch if it is not signed with a release certificate. This means phone app signed with only debug cert will not transfer the wearable app to watch. This is also noted in the documentation from link above. If you want to launch two apps at once (signed with debug cert) - this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075534/deploying-mobile-and-wear-at-the-same-time

Comment: It might be the same question (I didnt found it earlier), but it has no answers. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MaciejCiemięga so is it possible to have 1 app that can run on both phone and smartwatch? Do you know where I could find step by step procedure how to add wearable function to my existing appwidget?