# How do you add a watch module to an existing Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Google document "Creating and Running a Wearable App" (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) only discussed how to create a project from scratch. Let's say if you already have an Android Studio project for phone/tablet (imported from Eclipse), how do you add a watch module for Android Wear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Android Wear Module To My App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082055/add-android-wear-module-to-my-app)

Comment: That question already says he/she know how to do it "I looked around and found that the way to do this is to create new Android Wear Module and build it there.", and does not say how it is done. The question is about another thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right click your project,
open module settings,
hit the + sign which will take you to a wizard in which you can add a wear module

Comment: Thanks! That's a good start. My first observation: the versionCode / versionName for the original app (imported from Eclipse) remains at AndroidMenifest, but the new wear module is in build.gradle  - does it matter?

Comment: I would just copy versionCode and versionName from the Manifest into your build.gradle. That's what I did with my Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.0 ,it is shown in File -> Project Structure (F4)(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) .After this, click on the + sign.
    From there you can add wear,TV and other as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.x: File Menu/New/New Module...
Follow the wizard -> Select Wear OS